# Help identifying an OLD anime - a scene where a kid is in a printing press picking metal block letters?

Tags: ginga-tetsudou-no-yoru

I watched it in the early 90s, there is only one scene that I remember and was fascinated by.  A young boy was working at a printing press, picking out individual metal stamps and filling up a tray to prepare for each page to be printed.

For a better understanding of what I mean, it is also known as "movable type" or in Japanese "活版印刷機".

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: An anime from the early 90's is "old"? Damn, now you've made me feel ancient lol

Comment: Early nineties is TWENTY years ago. Try and remember how you felt about Disco when you were a child in the nineties, and you will get it.

Comment: @Mindwin oh I definitely understand. I don't think of 20 year old anime as old, which makes me feel prehistoric heh heh

Answer (score 3):

[Night on the Galactic Railroad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_on_the_Galactic_Railroad#Animated_film) is a classic Japanese novel from the 1920s that got an anime adaption in 1985 which has such a scene:

[image: typesetting scene from the anime]

The only thing that makes me doubt whether it's correct is that the protagonist is in fact a cat (as are all other characters).